# Migration from vtk5 to vtk7-> missing CopyIndormation from vtkPolyData

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, vtk

I am trying to migrate a program from vtk5.10 to vtk7.0 (QT 5.7, Visual Studio 2013). I have managed to do the proper changes in some functions. Although, now I get an error on a removed function (in vtk6) the CopyInformation.

> newOutput->CopyInformation(mapper->GetInput());

Is there any other fuction that could substitute this one in vtk7.0? I have searched on the vtk6 migration guides, but I couldn't find any helpful information  (for substitution). I am new in vtk, so any advice could help.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see this explanation? http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Removal_of_CopyInformation

Comment: @SimonKraemer Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have checked the explanation on migration guide, but I cannot find a way to change one of the executive classes.